# How can I calculate the time taken by a function to get executed with python?

Tags: python, performance, function, time

I called a ping command with subprocess. My calculated time difference is lower than the operational time.

latency: 361.953 [actual operation time]

calculated_latency: 0.7531721591949463 [calculated with python]

If python executes line by line, then calculated latency would be higher than the original one. I am not sure what is going on and how can I calculate the time of a function call.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime

command_line = "ping -c 1 {}".format('yahoo.com')
args = shlex.split(command_line)
try:
    start = time.time()
    output = subprocess.check_output(args)
    end = time.time()
    ping_latency_calculated = end - start

    result = str(output).strip("b'")

    m = re.search(r"\/(\d+\.\d+)\/", result)
    ping_latency = m.group(1)

    result = {'latency': ping_latency, 'calculated_latency': ping_latency_calculated}

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    result = {'Status': 'Ping Failed', 'time': datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())}

return result
```

Comment: I think it's because `calculated_latency` is counted in seconds and `latency` is counted in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks...! I should've noticed it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`calculated_latency` is counted in seconds and `latency` is counted in milliseconds.

So the result you get actually is:

```
latency: 361.953 ms
calculated_latency: 753.1721591949463 ms
```